# Magento 2 : Rest API error the requested URL returned error: 401

Tags: magento2.3, error, rest-api, curl, http-error-401

We have to test rest API is working or not in magento 2.3 but on my local project work only live site API not working.
We have to check site open or not using curl but it's not working. I am not able to find issue what.

**Curl code**

```
$your_url = "https://domain.com/rest/all/V1/categories?searchCriteria";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $your_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg)) {echo $error_msg;}
```

**Error**
The requested URL returned error: 401

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Add request type -**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Comment: It's not working